# OOEclipse on Ubuntu with LibreOffice - "invalid OOo path"

Tags: java, eclipse, openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno

I try to develop a LO extension in Java using Eclipse, but I can't get the OOEclipse plugin to work. Whenever I try to set the location of the LO installation, I get the "invalid OOo path" error.

I'm running

- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (I know, its old)
- libreoffice 4.0.2~rc2-0ubuntu1~lucid1 (from the PPA)
- libreoffice SDK (the same as above, from the PPA)
- Eclipse Juno
- OOEclipse (from http://drake79.users.sourceforge.net/ooeclipse/site/)

I can set the SDK path (/usr/lib/libreoffice/sdk), without any issue, and it is recognized as 400m1 - but the "Available OpenOffice.org" installation won't work.

Please, can anybody give me a hint on how to fix this so I can start coding the Calc function I desperately need (I got a Basic prototype, but I need a full fledged Extension)!

Answer (score 0):

About the "invalid OOo path" - the solution is to use the official LO packages, not the ones provided by the distribution or PPA.

Still, the plugin does not work, because the types.rdb file does not get generated (it'S deleted instead), but at least I could configure the plugin.

Maybe this helps someone else - I'll give netbeans a try.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is little late. It may be helpful for newcomer.

I was struggling with same issue "invalid OOo path.
I found the correct path. Its automatically created by dpkg when your install .deb libreoffice files.

Its located in /opt directory.

for me LibreOffice and its SDK path are /opt/libreoffice5.3 and /opt/libreoffice/sdk respectively.

Enjoy,
Cheeres.